# bitcoind RPC methods missing on Debian

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

Originally I installed `.bitcoind` using `--disable-wallet` then I later recompiled it with wallet. Not sure if that's to blame or how to troubleshoot.

Commands like this work:

```
bitcoin-cli getbestblockhash
```

> 0000000000000000000a40b6716fdd46ba98e238c58d3d686c653eeeb94aa759

but several others do not:

```
bitcoin-cli gettransaction "1075db55d416d3ca199f55b6084e2115b9345e16c5cf302fc80e9d5fbf5d48d"
```

> ```
> error code: -32601
> error message:
> Method not found
> ```

`bitcoin-cli getbalance`
>error code: -32601
>error message:
>Method not found

Using curl, i.e.

`curl --user bitcoinuser --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getinfo", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332`

also results in "method not found".

Comment: `1075db55d416d3ca199f55b6084e2115b9345e16c5cf302fc80e9d5fbf5d48d` does not appear to be a valid transaction on either Bitcoin or Bitcoin Testnet. What happens when you look up a valid transaction?

Comment: Did you restart bitcoind after reinstalling? The `Method not found` error means that `gettransaction` is not a method built into the currently running instance of bitcoind.